# display radio buttons in center of page

Tags: html, radio-button

Trying to get radio buttons, questions and answered centered in the middle of the page any help wud be great here is my code!!

```
 <form action='process.php?id=1' method='post' id='quizForm' id='1' onSubmit='validateForm()' name='myForm'>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <h3>1 x 1 =</h3>
            <div>
                <input type='radio' name='answerOne' id='answerOne' value='A' />
                <label for='answerOneA'>A)1</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type='radio' name='answerOne'  id='answerOne' value='B' />
                <label for='answerOneB'>B)2</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type='radio' name='answerOne' id='answerOne' value='C' />
                <label for='answerOneC'>C)3</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h3>1 x 6 =</h3>
            <div>
                <input type='radio' name='answerTwo' id='answerTwo' value='A' />
                <label for='answerTwoA'>A)5</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type='radio' name='answerTwo' id='answerTwo' value='B' />
                <label for='answerTwoB'>B)6</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type='radio' name='answerTwo' id='answerTwo' value='C' />
                <label for='answerTwoC'>C)4</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h3>2 x 8 =</h3>
            <div>
                <input type='radio' name='answerThree' id='answerThree' value='A' />
                <label for='answerThreeA'>A)14</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type='radio' name='answerThree' id='answerThree' value='B' />
                <label for='answerThreeB'>B)12</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type='radio' name='answerThree' id='answerThree' value='C' />
                <label for='answerThreeC'>C)16</label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Could you show us your CSS please?

Answer (score 0):

I have created basic fiddle for you with an example solution, check if that is what you need. 
http://jsfiddle.net/bhd2C/

I have simply put your form into a div for which I have created simple css class:

```
.content {
  width:100%
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form style='text-align:center' action='process.php?id=1' method='post' id='quizForm' id='1' onSubmit='validateForm()' name='myForm'>
<ol style='list-style-position:inside;'>
```

Changing first two lines would work. Setting text-align property to 'center' makes what is inside centered in the container. "list-style-position:inside;" code makes list styles( 1., 2. etc.) appear in normal flow so that they are also centered.

Note: text-align centers your content in the middle of container. That's, your container should be 100% width if you want to locate your content in the middle of the page.

Also note that when using css, internal or external style would be better instead of inline style( used in the code above) if you use it in other forms and lists.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7uw0.png)

[Ways to insert css](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

[How to create centered ordered list with HTML/CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494019/how-to-create-centered-ordered-list-with-html-css)

Comment: it centered the text but didnt center the radio buttons

Comment: It should :) I just added a result image. Make sure that is what you want since I don't know english much so I might misunderstand your problem. @user3543359